# Javafx Apply CSS to element of Custom-Menu-Item

Tags: css, javafx

I have a context menu with a single `custom-menu-item`. The custom-menu-item consists of a pane which in turns holds a **vbox**.

My goal is to get rid of the **blue highlighting**. I have successfully got rid of blue highlighting with the `context-menu`. But cannot access the layer below it (the pane or vbox). The context menu has been assigned `.context` as a class name.

```
FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/resources/fxml/ThePane.fxml"));
Pane pane = (Pane) fxmlLoader.load();
customMenuItem = new CustomMenuItem(pane);


.context .custom-menu-item:focused{
    -fx-background-color:white;
}

.context .custom-menu-item{
    -fx-background-color:white;
}
```

Comment: Did you try `customMenuItem.getStyleClass().add(".custom-menu-item")`? You mention that "The context menu has been assigned .context as a class name," but you probably need to assign a StyleClass (a CSS Class) to your CustomMenuItem as well.

Comment: the custom menu item part works just not the next layer. so Iam trying to access the content of the custom menu item which is in this case a pane

Comment: Unfortunately neither Pane nor VBox have a built in StyleClass you can use. You'll need to define your own and add it to your Pane specifically.

Comment: Ok thanks Ill try that